# How to Add String Url to Image source in C# and Xaml

Tags: c#, silverlight, xaml

I have String Array with Image Url

Sample Image from Array:

```
string Image = "https://fbcdn-profile-a.akamaihd.net/hprofile-ak-prn2/187738_100000230436565_1427264428_q.jpg";
```

Now i need to Bind Images in Xaml

```
<Image Name="img" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="66" Height="66" Source="{Binding Image} " />
```

trying to Give img.source But Not Accepting because con't Implement string to system.windows.media.imagesource

Comment: If you are binding you CAN use string. Where is the string (url) stored? what is the DataContext of the Image control?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Did you try setting `Source`:

```
var bitmapImage = new BitmapImage();
bitmapImage.BeginInit();
bitmapImage.UriSource = new Uri("https://fbcdn-profile-a.akamaihd.net/hprofile-ak-prn2/187738_100000230436565_1427264428_q.jpg");;
bitmapImage.EndInit();

img.Source = bitmapImage;
```

[Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms747027.aspx) is a bit more info.

**EDIT**

There is a possibility that this wont work for remote images (can't test it at the moment), I believe in such cases you need to download the image, so here is how you do it:

```
var imgUrl = new Uri("https://fbcdn-profile-a.akamaihd.net/hprofile-ak-prn2/187738_100000230436565_1427264428_q.jpg");
var imageData = new WebClient().DownloadData(imgUrl);

// or you can download it Async won't block your UI
// var imageData = await new WebClient().DownloadDataTaskAsync(imgUrl);

var bitmapImage = new BitmapImage {CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad};
bitmapImage.BeginInit();
bitmapImage.StreamSource = new MemoryStream(imageData);
bitmapImage.EndInit();

return bitmapImage;
```

Comment: Yes I try this Same error string to system.windows.media.imagesource error

Comment: @SriramSatti In case this doesn't work for remote images, I've added another approach.

Comment: Thanks for Al Your Replys... I got that with Single line of Code img.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("https://fbcdn-profile-a.akamaihd.net/hprofile-ak-prn2/187738_100000230436565_1427264428_q.jpg", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));